# Java Threadpool TCP Server (Port keeps changing!!)

Tags: java, tcp, threadpool

Good Day,

I was taking a look at this tutorial to do a TCP Threadpool server.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html

It works great for listening/RECEIVING to clients and processing, and returning a response. There is a class inside that I pass in WorkerRunnable into, and that basically prints out the remote socket address (who it was sent from)

```
    public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    while(! isStopped()){
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(isStopped()) {
                System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error accepting client connection", e);
        }
        this.threadPool.execute(
            new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket,
                "Thread Pooled Server"));
    }
    this.threadPool.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
}
```

The problem is. The remote address is supposed to stay fixed (I am working within my own home wifi router). However, the IP address of the sender stays the same, but the port keeps changing!!

This is a big problem for me..as I need to be able to return a response to the user for future tasks and I actually save this address to use again to send data. When I ran this in a single TCP thread..it stayed fixed (the port).

Why does the threadpool cause the TCP remote address port to keep changing?

Answer (score 2):

With TCP, the client socket port is most of the time (almost 99%, except for specific protocols) randomly chosen. But to you don't have to know it, the only thing you have to do is to keep the `clientSocket` reference to write back data to the client. If you want to  send data to the other host after that the connection is closed, you have to start a `ServerSocket` on both sides with a fixed port.

Comment: Can I have more detail on this ServerSocket? What is the difference. I want my server to send data back to the client but I don't know it's IP. And I cant hold a TCP connection open forever can i..

Comment: @user1436508, forever probably not (due to socket timeouts, firewalls, ...) but if you exchange data regularly you can keep it quite a long time, maybe a full day long. You can also set keepalive to true on client side `socket.setKeepAlive(true)` . If you really want to be able to join the client at any time, you will have to implement your TCP Server on both sides, and i.e. tell the client at the first connection to send to the server the port number it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you test from same machine the client port will be random by default. I am not sure if there is any way to set the client source port. However, if you use netstat or capture the packet you can be sure the source port is different for every connection.

Comment: I think you deserve some reassurance that providing insights to old, even extremely old, questions is actually appreciated on StackOverflow (maybe obvious why I think so...). Sadly I lack the technical expertise on this topic, so please understand that I cannot upvote. Also, only from my clueless point of view, I seem to see some similarities to the older answer. I can see the difference, that you state "be sure" while the other says "99%". For me that seems relevant difference. But whether I am right or not, you might want to make the difference more obvious.